# i want to create empty texture slots so i can add texture images later on

Tags: texturing

I have a model and 3 texture images to go with it. But if i open the model in an editor (dota 2 model editor) it only shows 1 available texture slot. So i can pick one of the 3 texture images, but of course it looks really bad.

At first i could not open the model in blender (its in fbx) because it was too old. So i used fbx converter to convert to a more recent version.

The 3 objects are still there , separately but they have no texture slot assigned to them, like i usually see.

So my question is, how can i add individual texture slots to each of the 3 meshes, so that later on i can insert my already existing texture files separately.

EDIT : i use blender render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must make sure a material is assigned to your mesh. Then in the texture tab you can add as many textures as you please to the list at the top. Under the "Image" section you can open a file browser window to choose your textures.
[image]

If no texture is selected it should just show a big button to open an image.

You can then mix the textures or make them affect different properties, like normal and specular under the "Influence" section.

[image]